# TemplateBinding gives error DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

I am having trouble to understand why a `{DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}` occurs and to be honest also what it exactly means.  I have a case with "borrowed code" that works perfectly well in the original solution but not in my project.

There are three style definitions:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ButtonBase}}" />
<Style TargetType="c:DropDownButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ButtonBase}}" />
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
....
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
            <Border x:Name="PART_border"
                    ....
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                   orizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

`Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` gives the error, with a hard-coded color it works as expected.
When I deactivate `<!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBrush}"/>-->` the exception occurs too, however only *after* the app has loaded and is visible. Isn't that rather strange?

I cannot figure out why the original project doesn't have this issue.
Solution was: wpf must find the brushes before it applies the style.
In my case I moved the Brushes in use before the Style definition.
I understand the "strange behavior" above as that wpf applies the brushes at a later point in time and hence throws the exception at a later point.

Comment: The [`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) *Specifies a static value that is used by the WPF property system rather than null to indicate that the property exists, but does not have its value set by the property system*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your brush is placed in a different Resource Dictionary it does recognize that such a key exists in your app at compile time but as i understand it there is no guarantee to when the resource is applied .

use a **DynamicResource** in this case to solve the problem .

Comment: O well, solved. Triggered by your post, I saw that the order of my brushes was different compared to the original project. My brushes  are in the same Resource Dictionary, but were placed áfter the Style definition were they were used. Changing the order resolved it.